# Broken Spring Configuration Editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, xml-editor

I am having slight difficulties as of late with my eclipse installation. Necessary Background information: We decided to use a specific version of the Spring Tool Suite (3.8.1 to be precise) with a specific set of plugins as our common developing environment.
So what we did is this, we fetched the 3.8.1 STS, modified the default config so work with our gradle plugins and then repacked that so it could be easily distributed in our network.
After this, we installed the plugins in one of the clients and then pushed the `plugins` and `dropins` folder onto our network share as well, so we could easily update the plugins without having to repack the entire thing every time we decide on a plugin upgrade.

This worked fine on almost all machines, except one, but we this that has something to do with the fact that the user in question has a second version of the Spring Tool Suite on his Computer.
However, roughly 2 days ago, I had to reset my installation because I carelessly updated too many modules and was unable to use the installation history to revert to the previous setting.

After I removed my current installation and purged the workspace, I reinstalled, reimported my projects and tried to work. This went fine until I tried to open a `Spring Bean Configuration xml file` with the provided `Spring config editor` - My IDE showed just an empty tab without title or content. After that, I tried to open the same file with any other internal XML editor, all showed the same - an empty tab. When creating a new Java Project, all XML Files are opened and displayed correctly though. But as soon as I try to open an XML file with the Spring Config Editor, I cannot open XML files in that project at all - except with a regular text editor.

Plus, sometimes my workspace gets addled by that so it generates an error and prevents eclipse from even starting.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening and what to do against it?

More Specs:

- STS Version: 3.8.1
- Eclipse Version: Eclipse Neon
- Plugins: (all fetched on Jan 11, 2017)

  - Buildship Gradle Integration
  - Minimalist Gradle Editor
  - EclEmma & JaCoCo
  - SonarLint
  - Eclipse Metrics
  - Thymeleaf Content Assist
  - JBoss Community Plugins

Answer (score 0):

A solution here was to use `STS -clean`, as that cleanes the data one most often misses.

in this case, it was workspace metadata that seems to have caused the error.